# Wordpress - Sub Menu Item's not showing

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have added sub menu items to my main menu `navigation`, but they are not showing at all?

I have checked the `css`, and do not see any code that would hide the sub menu.

```css
ul.art-hmenu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 13px;
}
ul.art-hmenu, ul.art-hmenu ul {
    min-height: 0;
}
ul.art-hmenu, ul.art-hmenu ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
table, ul.art-hmenu {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.art-hmenu {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="art-hmenu menu-2">
  <li class="menu-item-12 active"><a title="Home" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/" class="active">Home</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-14"><a title="Find Us" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/find-us/">Find Us</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-105"><a title="Facilities" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/facilities/">Facilities</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-207"><a title="Tours" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/tours/">Tours</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-229"><a title="Conferences" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/conferences/">Conferences</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-67"><a title="Contact" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/contact/">Contact</a> </li>
  <li class="menu-item-234"><a title="About Us" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/about-us/">About Us</a> </li>
</ul>
```

What am I overlooking or doing wrong that is hiding my sub menu?

Comment: Can you please add whole menu code with sub menu's becuase on below question there is no submenu.

Comment: currently you do not have any kind of submenu, that's why its not visible

Comment: Exactly, Please add sub menu's

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="art-hmenu menu-2">
    <li class="menu-item-12 active"><a title="Home" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-14"><a title="Find Us" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/find-us/">Find Us</a>
        <ul class="with-your-submenu-css-class">
            <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-105"><a title="Facilities" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/facilities/">Facilities</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-207"><a title="Tours" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/tours/">Tours</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-229"><a title="Conferences" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/conferences/">Conferences</a>
        <ul class="with-your-submenu-css-class">
            <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-67"><a title="Contact" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-234"><a title="About Us" href="http://agl.run-time.co.za/about-us/">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>


ul.art-hmenu {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 13px;
padding-right: 13px;
}
ul.art-hmenu, ul.art-hmenu ul {
min-height: 0;
}
ul.art-hmenu, ul.art-hmenu ul {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
table, ul.art-hmenu {
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
.art-hmenu {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: thank you.   Where in my wordpress files would I add the sub menu links ?

Comment: There is no other file to add menus but you need to create pages and then add menus on that from admin side.

Comment: are you referring to the "page template" ?